# add character to particular field using awk

Tags: shell, awk

How to add '0' to the first and 9th digit of 2nd field using awk?

data

```
  12345,20150303024955
```

output

```
  12345,0201503030024955
```

I am just new to shell script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming by "add to" you mean "prefix with":

```
$ echo '12345,20150303024955' |
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {sub(/.{8}/,"&0",$2); $2="0"$2}1'
12345,0201503030024955
```

Answer (score 0):

You asked for `awk` but this is also easy to do in `sed`:

```
$ echo '12345,20150303024955' | sed -r 's/,(.{8})/,0\10/'
12345,0201503030024955
```

How it works

- `-r`

  Turn on extended regex so that we don't need backslash escapes.
- `s/,(.{8})/,0\10/`

  Look for a comma followed by eight characters.  Replace that with a comma, a zero, those eight characters, and another zero.